# Why am I getting the same values for my Keras and Sklearn metrics?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, data-science

I have matrices for y_true and y_pred. This will give you some sense of the data:

```
print(y_true.shape)
print(y_pred.shape)

(12673, 4)
(12673, 4)
```

```
print(y_true[-3:])
print(y_pred[-3:])

[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

When I input y_true and y_pred to Keras and Sklearn metrics packages, I'm getting the same values. I've tried restarting my runtime and re-running everything, but that didn't help.

Here is the output that I'm getting:

```
print(f"F1 = {f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')}")
print(f'Accuracy = {accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)}')
print(f"Precision = {precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')}")
print(f"Recall = {recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')}")
```

Output:

```
F1 = 0.7529393198137774
Accuracy = 0.7529393198137774
Precision = 0.7529393198137774
Recall = 0.7529393198137774
```

f1:

```
f1 = tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=num_classes, average='micro')
f1.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
f1_result = f1.result().numpy()
print(f1_result)

0.75293934
```

Accuracy:

```
accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
accuracy.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
accuracy_result = accuracy.result().numpy()
print(accuracy_result)

0.75293934
```

Precision:

```
precision = tf.keras.metrics.Precision() #no need for micro?
precision.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
precision_result = precision.result().numpy()
print(precision_result)

0.75293934
```

Recall:

```
recall = tf.keras.metrics.Recall() #no need for micro?
recall.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
recall_result = recall.result().numpy()
print(recall_result)

0.75293934
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: why do you think the result should vary? I would expect that for the same data F1 score from sklearn should be the same as from tf.keras

Comment: Fair point - but ALL the metrics are outputting the same values! To me that doesn't seem right since the underlying equations are different.